# MariaDB trigger to perform an UPDATE and then an INSERT on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I currently have an `account` table and an `account_audit` table (all codes are available on a fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=1f97e7d6ac1765522ec97686a58cc750)).

I have two triggers that insert records into the account_audit table based on data inserted into the account table.

1 trigger is an ON INSERT trigger which just inserts these values - that works fine.

So, after inserting 2 records on my audit table - I have two records in both tables as below.

```
SELECT * FROM account;
```

gives

```
acct_id acct_name   acct_balance    tax_rate    acct_opened
      1 Bill            100.00          0.10     2019-11-01
      2 Ben            1000.00          0.10     2019-11-01
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM account_audit;
```

gives

```
acct_id txn_id  acct_name   acct_balance    tax_rate    valid_from  valid_to
      1      1       Bill         100.00        0.10    2021-11-07  2038-01-19
      2      2        Ben        1000.00        0.10    2021-11-07  2038-01-19
```

All is good - 2038 is MariaDB infinity - at least in temporal tables!

**But**, my UPDATE trigger is as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER testtrigger_upd 
AFTER UPDATE ON account
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE account_audit SET valid_to = NOW() 
    WHERE ((valid_to = '2038-01-19') AND (OLD.acct_name = NEW.acct_name));
    INSERT INTO 
      account_audit (acct_id, acct_name, acct_balance, tax_rate) 
      VALUES 
      (
        OLD.acct_id, 
        OLD.acct_name, 
        NEW.acct_balance, 
        OLD.tax_rate
        
        -- valid_from - NOW()!
        -- valid_to DEFAULTs to '2038-01-19' which is what we want for updates to balance 
      );
END;
```

So, when I UPDATE a balance on an account, I want the account_audit trail to reflect this and then to have the most recent (before the insert) balance record go to `valid_to` (today) and the new records `valid_from` today to `valid_to` in 2038 (infinity for MariaDB?).

The problem is that when I run this statement

```
UPDATE account 
SET acct_balance = acct_balance + 50 WHERE acct_name = 'Bill';  -- name is UNIQUE
```

the records in the account_audit table become:

```
acct_id txn_id  acct_name   acct_balance    tax_rate    valid_from  valid_to
      1      1       Bill         100.00    0.10        2021-11-07  2021-11-07
      1      3       Bill         150.00    0.10        2021-11-07  2038-01-19
      2      2        Ben        1000.00    0.10        2021-11-07  2021-11-07
```

You can see that Bill's record has been inserted but the **problem** is that Ben's record has also been updated with the date of today's insert - I only want this to happen for Bill obviously!

I have `WHERE ((valid_to = '2038-01-19') AND (OLD.acct_name = NEW.acct_name));` in my trigger and I have tried lots of others - `WHERE OLD.acct_id = NEW.acct_id` and I tried changing the UPDATE to use acct_id instead of name - nothing works. I tries swapping OLD. and NEW. order - try BEFORE or AFTER UPDATE - I really lose my head!

How can I rewrite trigger to update the account_audit table for **only** the person whose account it is and not for all accounts - that is to say, only update Bill's account and not Ben's one?

I know about the temporal table functionality - I don't want to use that because this is for a study and I have to use the triggers!

Fiddle is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=1f97e7d6ac1765522ec97686a58cc750).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the where clause

`WHERE ((valid_to = '2038-01-19') AND (OLD.acct_name = NEW.acct_name));`

is valid for both Ben and Bill. So it would update for both of them.

A solution could be to change it slightly to:

`WHERE ((valid_to = '2038-01-19') AND (acct_name = OLD.acct_name));`

Comment: `WHERE ((valid_to = '2038-01-19') AND (acct_name = OLD.acct_name));` - that [got it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=1cf8d8b131e6703903e68c78aebb29f9)! If you'd care to write it up, I'll happily mark as correct  and upvote. Simple error but I beginner with MySQL/MariaDB triggers...

Comment: I appreciate that very much! I've updated it now. It was a good question. When you're in the thick of things, it can be tough to see the forest through the trees.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct - also tried to upvote it - don't have 15 rep. yet, but it said that my vote was noted - so hopefully you'll get more points down the line!

Answer (score 1):

That is because your your where clause is for all rows true

So change the update query to check against the table

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER testtrigger_upd 
> AFTER UPDATE ON account
>   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
>     UPDATE account_audit SET valid_to = NOW() 
>     WHERE ((valid_to = '2038-01-19') AND (acct_name = NEW.acct_name));
>     INSERT INTO 
>       account_audit (acct_id, acct_name, acct_balance, tax_rate) 
>       VALUES 
>       (
>         OLD.acct_id, 
>         OLD.acct_name, 
>         NEW.acct_balance, 
>         OLD.tax_rate
>         
>         -- valid_from - NOW()!
>         -- valid_to DEFAULTs to '2038-01-19' which is what we want for updates to balance 
>       );
> END;
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE account 
> SET acct_balance = acct_balance + 50 WHERE acct_name = 'Bill';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM account_audit
> ```
>
> ```
> acct_id | txn_id | acct_name | acct_balance | tax_rate | valid_from | valid_to  
> ------: | -----: | :-------- | -----------: | -------: | :--------- | :---------
>       1 |      1 | Bill      |       100.00 |        0 | 2021-11-07 | 2021-11-07
>       2 |      2 | Ben       |      1000.00 |        0 | 2021-11-07 | 2038-01-19
>       1 |   null | Bill      |       150.00 |        0 | null       | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a02a716bab46cda25170744ef2e4aab7)*